# Implications of reading `byte` vs. `bytearray` from file in python

Tags: file, python-3.x, arrays, byte

I constantly get errors when reading from file as `bytes`, if I use upon them `ord()` or `chr()`. What could be the reason?

Comment: `ord` gives the ordinal for a string. In 3.x it's fairly pointless to use this for `bytes`. When you index or iterate over `bytes` you get integers in the range 0-255, e.g. `b'a'[0] == 97` or `list(b'\x01\x02\x03') == [1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read one `byte` from file, it would be represented as a byte character (and you should use `ord()` with it):

```
>>> print(index_file.read(1))
b'\x0a'
```

If you read an array of bytes, i.e. `bytearray`, each member of the array would be simple `int` (and you should use `chr()` with it):

```
>>> print(index_file.read(2)[0])
10
```

Comment: In both cases above you read a `bytes` object. A `bytearray` is a *mutable* type that's otherwise similar to the *immutable* `bytes`. For both types, indexing/iterating returns an integer in the range 0-255.